# Issue with extending BaseActivity for navigation drawer

Tags: android

I have looked around SO as well as Google searches, and have decided that my activities extending a BaseActivity was the best way to integrate a navigation drawer in my project. Whenever I start my app though, it crashes immediately. Below I have included my BaseActivity code and the issue lies with this line:

```
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
```

It results in a NullPointerException

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ListView drawerList;
    public String[] layers;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    Intent twitch = new Intent(this, TwitchActivity.class);
    Intent community = new Intent(this, CommunityActivity.class);
    Intent esports = new Intent(this, ESportsActivity.class);
    Intent home = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle((Activity) this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_launcher, 0, 0)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                actionBar.setTitle(R.string.menu);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        layers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.layers);
        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, android.R.id.text1,
                layers));


        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
                String selected = arg0.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                if(selected.equals("Twitch"))
                    startActivity(twitch);
                if(selected.equals("Community"))
                    startActivity(community);
                if(selected.equals("ESports"))
                    startActivity(esports);
                if(selected.equals("Home"))
                    startActivity(home);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

private Spinner spinner;
public static String region;
public static String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //.........
```

My drawer_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Nav Drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Full Error:

```
04-10 20:17:25.409    4548-4548/edu.appdesign.leaguestats E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edu.appdesign.leaguestats, PID: 4548
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.appdesign.leaguestats/edu.appdesign.leaguestats.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08003d type #0x12 is not valid
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08003d type #0x12 is not valid
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
            at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:34)
            at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your XML code, and your modified code, and copy the entire log stack. This will help us to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I have added my drawer_layout.xml, and the error log. Also, the code I had edited from the below answer is added in.

Comment: Your layout should be R.layout.drawer_layout

Comment: Yea I saw that pointed out below. I fixed that, and the icon for the nav drawer appears, but I cannot seem to pull it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `onCreate()` must call [setContentView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29) to set the layout *before* it calls `findViewById()` to get a view from within that layout. And make sure that you pass to `setContentView()` the proper layout resource (it should be something like 'R.layout.xxxxx', where 'xxxxx' is the name of your XML layout file, without the '.xml' extension).

Comment: Adding that in makes perfect sense, and I'm not sure how I missed it, but it did not fix the issue. When I do: someActivity extends BaseActivity, should I still be using onCreate(savedInstanceState)? Not sure if that is relevant to the issue.

Comment: Actually, the error changed to a NPE at:         setContentView(R.id.drawer_layout);

Comment: 2 related things to check: BaseActivity.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) *must* call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState). Also, if your subclass implements onCreate(), it also needs to call super.onCreate.

Comment: I have added some code to my original post if you want to take a look at my onCreate() in my MainActivity as well as the change you mentioned to my BaseActivity.

Comment: The exception is saying that the resource that you passed to setContentView() could not be found. You should be passing in something like R.layout.xxxxx, not R.id.yyyyy. The xxxxx should be the name of your xml layout file (without the .xml extension).

Comment: Ahh simple mistake. That added in the nav drawer, or at least the icon for it. I cant activate it though, as tapping it does nothing. Any idea?

Comment: That sounds like a totally new issue, and you should probably search for an answer or start a new Question here. As a thought, though, make sure your manifest is declaring that your starting Activity has the appropriate action and category intent filters. See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ExampleFilters